# Filtering id value from Array using java

Tags: java, arrays, filter, match

I am trying to filter the id value which matches a certain variable and return the id

```
result = {
    "drives": [{
        "id": "0AEz3mOk9PVA",
        "name": "Dev2020-10"
    }, {
        "id": "0AMEH9PVA",
        "name": "Dev2020-11"
    }, {
        "id": "0AAPUk9PVA",
        "name": "Dev2020-12"
    }
]
```

folderName = Dev2020-12

code:

```
if(result.toString().contains(folderName)) {                        
    return result; 
} else {
    // ...
}
```

I need to match the value in the result and return only the id of the matched drive name.

expected output:

"0AAPUk9PVA"

How can i achieve this

Comment: What is `result`? Map or JSONObject?

Comment: Its actually a array list

Comment: what is the type of the result object? if an array, what are the types of the contained objects? from java 8 you could use stream() and filter()

Comment: ArrayList of which objects?

Comment: add more code and context to your question

Comment: result is actually Drive List type from google drive. DriveList result;

Answer (score 1):

As soon as `result` appears to be `com.google.api.services.drive.model.DriveList`, you can try the following:

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Drive;

Optional<String> folderNameDriveId = result.getDrives().stream()
    .filter(drive -> folderName.equals(drive.getName()))
    .map(Drive::getId)
    .findFirst();
```

Comment: It is not allowing me to get the drive Id. Error: The type Drive does not define getId(Drive) that is applicable here

Comment: Do you import the right Drive class? Updated my answer with import

Answer (score 0):

`result.stream().filter(i -> i.get("name").equals(foderName)).findAny().orElse(null)`

the check inside the filter call will depend on the type of objects you have in your ArrayList